# Customização e z-Index

Tags: javascript, html, css

Procurei aqui pelo site e acabei não encontrando na que satisfaça minha dúvida. Tenho duas caixas, onde uma fica atrás da outra. Após eu clicar em um botão, gostaria que o z-index se alterasse para que a outra caixa venha para a frente (como se a pessoa tivesse mudado de link, mas isso não acontecerá). Além disso, um problema que tenho é que não estou conseguindo centralizar essas duas caixas na página.
A questão de centralizar é que eles se encontram no lado superior esquerdo da página, e não ao seu centro.

Ps: coloquei a tag de JS por supor que é por ele que se faz a questão do index do second-content se alterar para o first-content. Se não for isso, por favor me corrijam e irei alterar.

```
<form action="registrarDespesas.php" method="POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data" name="registro">

    <div class="container">

    <div class="content first-content">

            <div class="first-column">
                <h2 class="title title-grey">Insira os dados de sua despesa.</h2>


            </div>

            <div class="second-column">
              <p>
              <select size="1" name="tipoDespesa" class="select" required style="margin-left:2px;">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo</option>
              <option>Almoço</option>
              <option>Jantar</option>
              <option>Quilometragem</option>
              <option>Gasolina</option>
              <option>Pedágio</option>
              <option>Táxi/Uber</option>
              <option>Estacionamento</option>
              <option>Passagem | Ônibus</option>
              <option>Passagem | Metrô/Trem</option>
              <option>Cursos/Treinamentos</option>
              <option>Outras</option>
              </select>
              <p><input type="number" name="numeroKm" placeholder="KM" id="km" step=".1" style="display: none; height: 30px;width: 150;padding-left: 10px;">
              <input type="number" name="precoDespesa" placeholder="R$" id="valor" step=".01" required placeholder="Insira um valor!"></p>
              <p><input type="date" class="data" name="data" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" required placeholder="Insira uma data válida!">
              <input type="text" name="limiteDespesa" id="limite" readonly></p>
              <p><input type="file" name="fotoDespesa" id="file" required placeholder="É necessário o envio da despesa!"></p>
              <textarea name="observacao" placeholder="Deixe quaisquer observações aqui!"></textarea>
              <p><button type ="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-grey">registrar</button></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-grey" href="areaUsuario.php" style="text-decoration:none;">finalizar</a></p>
              <a class="btn btn-grey" href="selecionarProjeto.php" style="text-decoration:none;">voltar</a>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content second-content">

        <div class="third-column">
        <h2 class="title title-grey h22">Selecione o projeto.</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="quarter-column">
        <p><select class="select2" name="tipoProjeto">
        <option>KHEDI</option>
        <option>LCSC</option>
        <option>CCS</option>
        </select>
        <p><a class="btn btn-grey-avancar" href="registrarDespesas.php" style="text-decoration:none;">avançar</a></p>
        <a class="btn btn-grey-voltar" href="areaUsuario.php" style="text-decoration:none;">voltar</a>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

e aqui está o CSS ao qual estou referenciando:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -170px;

}

.content{
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: darkslategray;
    width: 960px;
    height: 60%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
}

.content::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #EBBE17;
    width: 58%;
    height: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.title{

    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.title-white{
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title-grey{
    color: darkslategray;
}

.description{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.btn{
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: inline-block;

}

.btn{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color .4s;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: darkslategray;
}

.first-content{
    display: flex;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;

}

.first-column{
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.second-column{
    z-index: 1;
    flex: 1.4 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 55%;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;


}


select{
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
    color:darkslategray;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

input{
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
    color:darkslategray;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;

}


#valor{
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 30px;
}

textarea{
    width: 71.5%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 70px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#file{
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

h2{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.btn-grey {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.data {
    height: 30px;
    width: 170px;
    padding-left:6px;
}

#limite {
    width: 128px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
}

.fas{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.second-content {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.btn-grey-avancar{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color .4s;
}

.btn-grey-voltar{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color .4s;
}

.select2 {
    height: 30px;
    width: 570%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
    color:darkslategray;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.h22{
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.third-column{
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.quarter-column{
    z-index: 1;
    flex: 1.4 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
```

Comment: cria duas classes com os `z-index` diferentes e troca elas no click

Comment: Como eu poderia realizar isso com o javascript? Não entendo muito da linguagem ainda.

Comment: use a propriedade `classList`, veja isso: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

Eu olhei o seu código e fiz de um jeito aqui que a gente não vai mexer na propriedade `z-index` mas sim na propriedade `display` dos seus contêiners.

Mas antes vamos arrumar seu CSS para os contêiners ficarem no centro da página.

1. Na classe *.container* tire a declaração `margin-top: -170px;`.
2. Nas classes *.first-content* e *.second-content* tire a declaração `position: absolute;`
3. Na classe *.first-content* mude o diplay para none, assim: `diplay: none;`
4. Deixe o body com as margens zeradas, assim: `body { margin: 0; }`

Isso já deve ser suficiente para deixar tudo centralizado do jeito que você quer.

---

Agora vamos fazer um script para realizar a "troca" dos contêiners quando o botão **AVANÇAR** for clicado.
No final do seu código, uma linha antes do `</body>`, adiciona o seguinte script:

```
<script>
  function trocaDiv(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var firstContent = document.getElementsByClassName("first-content")[0];
    firstContent.style.display = 'flex';
    var secondContent = document.getElementsByClassName("second-content")[0];
    secondContent.style.display = 'none';
  }
</script>
```

Depois, na tag do botão **AVANÇAR**, você vai ter que adicionar `onclick="trocaDiv()"`. Ficando assim:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-grey-avancar" href="registrarDespesas.php" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="trocaDiv()">avançar</a></p>
```

Só isso acredito que já vai ser suficiente para rodar do jeito que você espera, mas além disso tem alguns outros errinhos. Essa tela funciona bem em um monitor grande, mas não tem responsividade para monitores menores. Mas rodando do jeito que você espera já é algo bom, depois você pode ir atrás de deixar mais responsivo.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida chama aí.

Abraços.